# No Orgs for User IBM Cloud Tools for Swift

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

Getting this error:

> No Orgs for User. Go to Bluemix.net and sign in to create your org

When using IBM Cloud Tools for Swift.

There is an org created in the Bluemix account.

Comment: I have changed the region to UK and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to the latest version. Originally we defaulted to US South but the latest should check the orgs and spaces in different regions and default you to another one that has both. If this is not the case please let me know and we will file a defect to fix this for our next update.